# PHP: Replace CSS comments with other comments

Tags: php, css, comments, preg-replace

I have this piece of code:

```
$csscomments = '!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!';
$sourcecode = preg_replace($csscomments, '<span class="csscomments">'.$csscomments.'</span>', $sourcecode);
```

That works fine to find CSS comments but it definitely doesn't replace them with what I need.

For example, I need to replace:  `/* Hello world */` with `<span class="csscomments">/* Hello world */</span>`.

And now I get this as an output `!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!`.

What do I need to change to get the correct output? Thank you!

Comment: preg_replace works as follows: `preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);` your pattern and replacement are there, yet your string is empty. (also preg_replace does not need assignment)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite answering your question but kinda fixing the problem you weren't even asking about in the first place (I think):

```
preg_match($csscomments, $stringcontainingyourCSS?, $matches);
$sourcecode = array();
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    array_push($sourcecode, "<span class='csscomments'>" . $match . "</span>");
}
```

Comment: Thats a good point, i already thought about it, that i didn't get the matching text in the string.